# Snort false positive, yet suspicious

Tags: snort

I have Snort installed and tuned nicely with ET Rules on my pfSense,
both my pfSense and the modem are using Googles public DNS 8.8.8.8.

Recently I was denied access to google.com, and by reviewing the logs,
I found the following records in the blocked list for the same IP:

- ET INFO Possible Chrome Plugin install
- SENSITIVE-DATA Credit Card Number

I did  suppressed the offending IP for further investigation which revealed it's one of my ISP IPs with ports 80,443 and OS Fingerprint CPE: cpe:/o:freebsd - nmap tells.

A traceroute to the offending IP ends on hop 10 with a virtual/private IP,
apparently a router in the AS system of my ISP with transparent proxy "?"

Later on I tried to access the offending IP from my web-browser and I got redirected to google.com.mycountry

Now I'm confused.
Could this be a Snort false positive?
Is there anything i should be worried about?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me it's possible snort was doing its job.

ET INFO Possible Chrome Plugin install

The above rule detects when a chrome extension was installed. So perhaps you installed one from google.

SENSITIVE-DATA Credit Card Number

The above rule matches any number in a packet that resembles a credit card. Perhaps one request you made contained a sequence of numbers that looked like a credit card.

The next questions
- verify each happened (what extension ? What number ?)
- do you want to monitor these rules ? Perhaps turn them off
- if left on , should they be blocking or just alerting ?

Snort rules require a lot of maintenance and tuning